# Text was not showing from right to left in Hebrew language in iOS 9.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9.1

In my app I am displaying some text in Hebrew. when it was in previous iOS versions it was working fine. When I am upgrade to iOS 9.1. It was showing like from left to right. But it should right to left. How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you please share your code? for what control you talking about ?

Comment: The text (text in Hebrew language) was assigned to UILabels and UITextview . And in previous versions it was working fine like it was from right to left. When in iOS9.1 it was from left to right. This is the issue.

Comment: Now in iOS 9.0 Xcode support automatic text direction according to language, so you no need do anything for that, Do you write any code for that ?

Comment: No. But text alignment from left to right in iOS9.1 for Hebrew language it seems like wrong. But in previous versions it was from right to left alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From iOS 9 onwards text direction sets automatically.
Just make sure that your UILable or UITextView text allignment is set to **NSTextAlignmentNatural**. If you are using storyboard or xib. you can set text direction like below image.

[image]